# Is there a in-built setting to login to public hotspots?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, certificates

I have a SIM-lock free Galaxy W with Android 2.3.6 on it.

The other day in the public library I found out that I was not able to login anyhow to the public Wi-Fi.

It shows that the DHCP gives the phone an IP address and then labels it as connected, but on the PC a "further data needed" kind of notification would appear in order for me to put username and password in.

Now I found the "Free Wi-Fi hotspot" that deals exactly with this and am going to test it today, but it looks just like a frontend. Really there is not a way to access them using only built-in options on Android?

EDIT: Trying opening my browser after connecting doesn't automatically redirect me anywhere. That's why I avoided using the term "captive portal" as I cannot see any portal.

Comment: Just for your information, newer Android versions, at least 4.1.1, show the notification you mentioned on hotspots that use a captive portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser when connected to that hotspot, it should automatically get re-directed to the login page for it. That is what most of these Hotspot apps try to automate using macros. After having logged-in via the browser, the internet connection should be available to your apps.

Comment: Strangely enough, trying my browser after connecting doesn't automatically redirect me anywhere. That's why I avoided using the term "captive portal" as I cannot see any portal.

Comment: That's strange. Did you ask the provider for that? To me it looks like a configuration problem with the proxy they probably use, as the procedure I described is IMHO standard.

Comment: Did you try going to a generic webpage? Most redirect Google.com to the login page if you are not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said that it isn't a 'Captive Portal', could it be an internal VPN connection? I doubt it, but it is possible.

Most hotspot's that require login use these portals - so you should just go to [google.com](http://www.google.com) in your browser and it should take you to a webpage that is the portal, where a login is required prior to accessing any other website.

This login, may require a registration or some form of payment, depending on who is the provider of that portal. Has this ever appeared before?

When you use your laptop - what does the balloon notification say, something along the lines of "Wifi Hotspot detected, click here to connect" or similar. On my laptop, it just opens my browser to my home page, to get redirected to the portal to login.